# Joomla: How to pass variables from the constructor in the model to the view?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Seems like this shouldn't be that hard but is giving me fits.

Have variables initialized in the model's __construct method.

Need to access them in the view.html.php and default.php files.

In my model:

```
$this->MyVar = 'somevalue';
```

In my view.html.php:

```
$model = $this->getModel('mymodelname');
print_r($model) //checking, yes - the model's being pulled in
$myvar = $model->__construct($this->MyVar);
echo $myvar; //empty
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

=========================================

Solution:

```
$model = $this->getModel('mymodelname');
echo $model->MyVar; // returns the variable in the model
```

Comment: The tags should be corrected, which version of Joomla are you using ? all three ?

Comment: 2.5 but it's a valid question for all the versions.  I think the tags for Joomla in general needs to be reviewed - this is a valid question in every version from 1.6 and up.

Comment: About the tags: there are major differences between the versions, for example, the ACL is totally different if you compare 1.5 with 1.6. It might not have a difference in your case - but you should still use only the relevant tags to prevent confusion.

Comment: There aren't major code differences in 1.6+  I'm not sure why you're talking about 1.5 - I didn't tag it and I'm not talking about it :/  However for users who are looking through Joomla tags for answers then again this question is valid for 1.6, 1.7, and 2.5.

Comment: I think you didn't notice I used the words `for example`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use construct at all after you have instantiated the model simply do like this:

```
$model = $this->getModel('mymodelname');
$model->MyVar = $myvar;
```

Answer (score 2):

`__construct()` does not return any value, this is why `$myvar` remains `null`. If you want, you can read more about it *[here](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJModel/_construct)*

According to the specification (in the link above) you should pass to `__construct` an associative array that could hold one or more of the following fields:

- `'name'`
- `'state'`
- `'dbo'`
- `'table_path'`

and according to what you say - you pass a parameter. Try:

```
$arr = array('name' => $this->MyVar);
$model->__construct($arr);
```

Comment: So there's no way of getting those values out?  Seems like there should be an easy way of passing values from the model to the view...

Comment: That's a different question... I believe that there should be a `getter` to the common stuff, but it needs further checking, plus, I have no idea what `$this->MyVar` holds...

Comment: $this-MyVar holds a short string, but it gets it by going through a bunch of functions. Still the same question; need that value, don't know how to get it :/  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: if you need the value why not just use: `$myvar = $this->MyVar;`

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I tried...which lead to a cascade of frustrations.

Comment: see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Been playing with that, no luck.  Since $this->MyVar is empty in the view.html.php it's passing an empty array to the constructor :/

Comment: In that case, you'll have to debug back to the place where you assign a value to `$this->MyVar`.

Comment: Thanks again for all your time on this - the trick was to bypass the constructor completely (solution posted).  Learning is painful and I have a long way to go!